# matplotlib 2d line line,=plot comma meaning

Tags: python, matplotlib, tuples, line

I'm walking through basic tutorials for matplotlib, and the example code that I'm working on is:

```py
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[5,6,7,8]

line, = plt.plot(x,y,'-')

plt.show()
```

Does anyone know what the comma after line (`line,=plt.plot(x,y,'-')`) means?
I thought it was a typo but obviously the whole code doesn't work if I omit the comma.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`plt.plot` returns a list of the `Line2D` objects plotted, even if you plot only one line.

That comma is unpacking the single value into `line`.

ex

```
a, b = [1, 2]
a, = [1, ]
```

Answer (score 10):

The `plot` method returns objects that contain information about each line in the plot as a list.  In python, you can expand the elements of a list with a comma.  For example, if you plotted two lines, you would do:

```
line1, line2 = plt.plot(x,y,'-',x,z,':')
```

Where `line1` would correspond to `x,y`, and line2 corresponds to `x,z`.  In your example, there is only one line, so you need the comma to tell it to expand a 1-element list.  What you have is equivalent to

```
line = plt.plot(x,y,'-')[0]
```

or

```
line = ply.plot(x,y,'-')
line = line[0]
```

Your code should work if you omit the comma, only because you are not using `line`.  In your simple example `plt.plot(x,y,'-')` would be enough.

Comment: It returns a `list`, not a `tuple`

Comment: @tcaswell OK, but it doesn't change the answer

Comment: no, but there is no reason to write something factually incorrect. It can matter in other cases if you want to do something fancier with the list of returned `Line2D` objects.

Comment: @tcaswell I didn't write tuple to be deliberately factually incorrect, just an honest mistake :).  I edited it to say list now.

Comment: I assumed it was a mistake, which is why I left a comment instead of just editing it. Sorry if I came across as accusatory.

Comment: This answer is comprehensive. Great info.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of the function is a tuple or list containing one item, and this syntax "unpacks" the value out of the tuple/list into a simple variable.

Answer (score 0):

in matplotlib documentation https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html

in 'Controlling line properties' section, it gives details about why this comma.
'''
Use the setter methods of a Line2D instance. plot returns a list of Line2D objects; e.g., line1, line2 = plot(x1, y1, x2, y2). In the code below we will suppose that we have only one line so that the list returned is of length 1. We use tuple unpacking with line, to get the first element of that list:
'''