# how to change the line in the same polar used matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a polar in python matplotlib.now I want to change the line I draw using the function 'plot()' in the same polar. how to do it? thanks very much!

following is my code

```
figure_az = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
self.canvas_az = FigureCanvas(sbSizer3.GetStaticBox(), -1, figure_az)
self.axes_az = figure_az.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
self.axes_az.set_theta_zero_location('N')
figure_az.set_facecolor('#F0F0F0')
self.axes_az.grid(color='#888888')
self.axes_az.set_theta_direction(-1)

self.axes_az.set_xticklabels(['0', '45', '90', '145', '180', '-145', '-90', '-45'], color='#111111', fontsize=10)
self.axes_az.set_axis_bgcolor('#111111')
self.axes_az.set_rticks([])
self.axes_az.set_rlabel_position(120)

r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = [0] * len(r)
self.axes_az.plot(theta, r, 'r')
```

but I don't know why it worked.
first I try to code this:

```
t = self.axes_az.plot(theta, r, 'r)
t.set_xdata(theta1) #theta1 is different from theta
```

but it can't work,the error is

```
list don't have attribute 'set_xdata'
```

then I changed to this:

```
t, = self.axes_az.plot(theta, r, 'r')
t.set_xdata(theta1)
```

and it worked. why it worked after I added a ',' ?
thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. The code already has a line plot in it; if you want to change it, what hinders you? Where is the problem?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have solved this problem. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python code. Is it comma operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037494/python-code-is-it-comma-operator)

Comment: Also: [matplotlib 2d line line,=plot comma meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742765/matplotlib-2d-line-line-plot-comma-meaning)