# How does unpacking in fig, ax = plt.subplots() work for more than one subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using python 2.7.

I've used the following code and applied it to my script: http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/data_browser.html

Now, I'm trying to figure some of the specific around how it works. Eg:

```
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
```

From what I know about using commas in python, it's used for unpacking. But in the code above, I can't relly understand what is being unpacked and why in that manner. Is:

```
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
```

the same as:

```
fig, ax, ax2 = plt.subplots(2, 1)
```

as in this code from matplotlib faq?:

```
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(2, 2)  # a figure with a 2x2 grid of Axes
```

does fig automatically equal to `fig = plt.figure()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [`plt.subplots()` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots), you find that it returns

> fig : `matplotlib.figure.Figure` object
>   ax : `Axes` object or array of `Axes` objects.
>   ax can be either a single `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object or an array of Axes objects if more than one subplot was created. The dimensions of the resulting array can be controlled with the squeeze keyword, see above.

Examples of usage cases are given below the function definition in the documentation.

So from this we learn that the return of `plt.subplots` is always a tuple. Tuples can be unpacked using the comma,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

The first element is a `matplotlib.figure.Figure`, which you you could indeed also get by calling `plt.figure()`.

The second element of the tuple `ax` can be a tuple as well, depending on the arguments used. If `n` rows or columns are created, `ax` is an `n`-tuple. This tuple can be unpacked again,

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
```

If more than one row *and* column are created, `ax` will be a tuple of tuples, which again can be unpacked with a comma

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
```

---

Finally, as in python

```
a,b,c   = (5, 6, 7)  # works
a,b,c   = (5,(6,7))  # does not work
a,(b,c) = (5,(6,7))  # works
```

you **cannot** do `fig, ax, ax2 = plt.subplots(2, 1)`, it will raise an error.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! But why would one want to use a,(b,c) = (5,(6,7)) instead of a,b,c = (5, 6, 7)? Won't the end result be the same? Or is it that a,(b,c) will return 'a' as per normal and then (b,c) as tuples?

Comment: If you write some code yourself, you may choose whatever best fits your needs `a,(b,c) = (5,(6,7))` or `a,b,c = (5, 6, 7)`, this is just an explanation for what is happening behind the scenes. Since `plt.subplots(2,1)` returns something in the form of `(5,(6,7))`, this is to explain why `fig, ax, ax2 = plt.subplots(2, 1)` does not work.

Comment: Nice, thanks for clearing that up! What about `line, = ax.plot(xs, ys, 'o', picker=5)`, i can't find anything about ax.plot returning multiple items. Why do we need to unpack line?

Comment: The [documentation of `plot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot) explicietely states: *"Return value is a list of lines that were added."*. In most cases you only produce one line, so the list contains only one line, which still needs to be unpacked. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742765/matplotlib-2d-line-line-plot-comma-meaning).

Comment: Sorry must have missed that part. Thanks again.