# Python to convert tuple to value

Tags: python, postgresql, iterable-unpacking

I'm trying to retrive number of rows in table
with:

```
import postgresql

db = postgresql.open(...)
res = db.query("select count(1) from testdata")
print(res)
```

```
>>> (10,)
```

How can I print just `10`?

Comment: `print(res[0])` what you're seeing is a `tuple` returned and not a `list`

Comment: @EdChum, thank you, I'll correct the theme

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to avoid having a tuple in the first place, you can unpack it on assignment with `res, = db.query("...")` (note the comma after `res`).

Comment: @jdehesa yes, it works, but how? can you explain or just give a link? Thank you, I'm really appreciate your help!

Comment: one more. how can i mark it as solved? )

Comment: Here is a related question [matplotlib 2d line line,=plot comma meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16742765/1782792), and [here](http://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/) there are more details and examples about tuple unpacking (single item tuple example near the end). You can just close the question since there is no actual answer posted and there are already similar questions covering the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.query()` returns a *tuple* of query results, even if the query seeks only one value. We can iterate through the response's results using the `next` method:

```
import postgresql

db = postgresql.open(...)
res = db.query("select count(1) from testdata")
count_result = res.next()
```

(see [*Data Wrangling with Python*](http://opencarts.org/sachlaptrinh/pdf/19847.pdf) p.212).

---

Alternative approaches:

```py
count_result = res[0] # first argument of res is the count
```

```py
count_result, *_ = db.query("select count(1) from testdata") 
# first argument assigned to `count_result`
# subsequent arguments unassigned
```