# Matplotlib: How to clear a plot element using its handle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't understand why this is so hard, but I can't figure out how to do it.  If I have multiple lines or points plotted and want to clear one of them, how is that done? Other posts point to `remove()`, but this is not working in my case.  See example:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:16:51) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> 
>>> plt.ion()
>>> x = np.arange(100.) / 99
>>> y = np.sin(x)
>>> fig, ax = plt.subplots()
>>> h = ax.plot(x, y)
>>> h.remove()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: remove() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Comment: Probably you want `h, = ax.plot(x, y)` as `plot()` returns a list (containing one element).  See [matplotlib 2d line line,=plot comma meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742765/matplotlib-2d-line-line-plot-comma-meaning)

Answer (score 1):

I think JohanC's answer is indeed correct. 
You can simply try putting a `print(h)` just before `h.remove()` line. We will notice a list object being returned. However, if you use `h = ax.plot(x, y)` instead and then use `print(h)`, we will see only one object like Line2D being returned (not a list) and `h.remove()` should work.

Comment: Do you mean to say "h, = ax.plot(x,y)", with the comma?