# deleting matplotlib scatterplot doesn't work with .remove()

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to find a way to remove a specific scatter plot in matplotlib but it seems I can't use the `.remove()` method like I already do with line plots objects.

To put a bit of context I am building a GUI for data manipulation and, each time I plot, I append a list that contains one triplet for each plot:

```
self.lines.append ([self.ax.plot(data[x_var], data[y_var], color=widget_color), widget_id, 0])
```

Here the first element is the plot object, the second one (`widget_id`) is a number ID of the dataset used, the 3rd is also a number ID for the ax used (0 for primary, 1 for secondary).

Then when I want to delete a specific line I just check in this list which ones have the corresponding dataset (`widget_id`) and ax id:

```
i = 0
while i < len(self.lines):  # Loop through the list of lines, using while because the list is modified in the loop
    if self.lines[i][1] == widget_id and self.lines[i][2] == axis:
        self.lines[i][0][0].remove()       # Remove the line from the plot
        del self.lines[i]  # Remove the line from self.lines
    else:
        i += 1
```

When I use this on line2d objects (plots made with the `plot` command) it works fine.
When I use this on a scatterplot (plot made with the `scatter` command) it returns this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mfeuvrie2022\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfeuvrie2022\Desktop\tez\python\data_guiV15 - Copie.py", line 815, in askmasterto_clear_plot
    self.master.clear_widget_plots(self.widget_id, 0)   #clear the primary axis of the widget
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mfeuvrie2022\Desktop\tez\python\data_guiV15 - Copie.py", line 427, in clear_widget_plots
    self.lines[i][0][0].remove()       # Remove the line from the plot
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
TypeError: 'PathCollection' object is not subscriptable
```

I have the feeling that I need to find each plotted point as objects to delete them all separately but I can't find documentation about this.

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: What is `type(self.lines[i][0])`?

Comment: Probably, you need to change `self.lines[i][0][0].remove()` to `self.lines[i][0].remove()`.  `plt.plot` returns a tuple of lines (usually a tuple with just one element). Other functions don't return tuples, just the element itself.  See e.g. [matplotlib 2d line line,=plot comma meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742765/matplotlib-2d-line-line-plot-comma-meaning). If all your line plots plot just one element, for consistency, you could add `[0]` in `self.lines.append ([self.ax.plot(...)[0]`.

Comment: "type(self.lines[i][0])=  <class 'matplotlib.collections.PathCollection'>"
When I do "self.lines[i][0].remove()" it indeed clears the plot but it also clears all the other plots, even though they have not been removed in "self.lines" I don't understand